How do I play a non-integer hz frequency using python 3?
I want to play various frequencies ascending in an octave and I made my python code calculate the frequencies, but winsound does not let me play non-integer hz values.
This is my code so far:
import winsound

a4_frequency_hz = 440

range_of_pitches = [2**(i/12) * a4_frequency_hz for i in range(13)]

for pitch in range_of_pitches:
    winsound.Beep(pitch, 1000)


What if the simple answer is that you can't?

Would you hear the difference if you rounded to the nearest integer? You might do better - and get proper chords - if you wrote MIDI notes to a MIDI device.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To produce a sound at a specific frequency, the sound system has to change its output at twice that frequency (with some fuzz due to anti-aliasing and filtering). Since Windows typically has a sampling frequency of 44.1 kHz or 48 kHz, it can approximate frequencies up to 22/24kHz - but it's an approximation, which gets rougher the closer you get to the maximum. Anything over the Nyquist frequency (half the sampling rate) cannot be rendered at all.
So, it doesn't really make sense to ask Windows to render non-integer frequencies. By the time you'd be able to tell the difference, it hardly matters anymore, and for even higher frequencies, it would be lost in the inaccuracies.
It's not impossible to render some non-integer frequencies with some audible difference, and I'm sure high end audio devices and libraries do, but choosing an integer frequency as an input for generating a single-frequency tone is a reasonable design choice.
If you need more control, you can generate your own waveform and ask winsound to play back the file. That gives Windows the exact sample values (an amplitude) to put through the system, resulting in the frequencies you need to hear (or as close as the system can get to it, disregarding other technical issues and psycho-accoustics).
Here's an example using scipy to do the math, and winsound for playback. If you're like me, it will sound like a single 4 second 100Hz tone (possibly with a tiny glitch in the middle), but perhaps you have super-hearing.
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile 

sample_rate = 44100
duration = 2
frequency = 100

t1 = np.linspace(0, duration, int(sample_rate * duration), endpoint=False)
wav1 = .5 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * frequency * t1)  # 100 Hz tone

t2 = np.linspace(0, duration, int(sample_rate * duration), endpoint=False)
wav2 = .5 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * (frequency + .5) * t2)  # 100.5 Hz tone

wav = np.concatenate((wav1, wav2))

combined_waveform_integers = np.int16(wav * 32767)

wavfile.write('two_tone.wav', sample_rate, combined_waveform_integers)

# --- playback

import winsound

winsound.PlaySound('two_tone.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)

(edit: I changed the frequency to 100 Hz to improve your odds of a JND - just noticable difference - but I can't hear a difference at any frequency)

it doesn't really make sense to ask Windows to render non-integer frequencies is not true, especially for low frequencies. Floating-point math and a correctly managed buffer will produce an accurate sine.

Whether the difference is audible to a human is separable and (for this question) irrelevant.

@Reinderien it's not at all irrelevant - it explains the design decision and manages expectations around finding this type of feature in any basic library with that type of function. Since the answer also provides a way to get it done anyway, I don't think this takes away from the answer in any way.

@Reinderien "accurate sine" that depends on your definition of accurate, and the usefulness of the tone generated. As the answer clearly shows, you can do well with the library requested. I don't think you're contributing much by being right on the internet here. I think the answer is clear about the context in which it should be taken.

The answer is definitely not "don't". If you play e.g. two of these programs side-by-side, one with 100 Hz and one with 100.5 Hz, you'll hear a very clear beat frequency. Beat frequencies are how musicians and technicians often perform tuning.
Do:

write to a buffer
use a portable audio framework
use floating-point math throughout
track phase

Don't:

write to disk
use winsound, unless you have a really good reason

Fundamentally, fine-grained control of an arbitrary frequency is very possible; you just need to make sure that your wave rendering is continuous and buffer-agnostic. Avoid discontinuity by saving a phase shift between buffers and using that phase shift to calculate your time series.
import time
import types
import typing
import numpy as np

import pyaudio


class NotePlayer:
    A1_FREQ = 55
    RATE = 48_000

    def __init__(self, gain: float = 0.5) -> None:
        self.audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream: pyaudio.Stream
        self.freq = 0.
        self.phase = 0
        self.gain = gain  # higher than 1 and the output will likely distort

    def __enter__(self) -> 'NotePlayer':
        self.stream = self.audio.open(
            input=False, output=True,
            stream_callback=self.callback,
            frames_per_buffer=1024,
            channels=1,
            rate=self.RATE,
            format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
            start=False,
        )
        return self

    def __exit__(
        self,
        exc_type: None | typing.Type[Exception],
        exc_value: None | Exception,
        traceback: None | types.TracebackType,
    ) -> bool:
        self.stream.close()
        self.audio.terminate()
        return False

    def callback(
        self,
        in_data: bytes | None,
        frame_count: int,
        time_info: dict[str, float],
        status_flags: int,
    ) -> tuple[bytes, int]:
        t = np.linspace(
            start=self.phase/self.RATE,
            stop=(self.phase + frame_count)/self.RATE,
            num=frame_count,
            endpoint=False,
            dtype=np.float32,
        )
        self.phase += frame_count

        theta = np.fmod(self.freq*t, 1)
        y = self.gain*np.sin(2*np.pi*theta)
        return y.tobytes(), pyaudio.paContinue

    def play_note(self, note: int) -> None:
        self.play_freq(self.A1_FREQ * 2**(note/12))

    def play_freq(self, freq: float) -> None:
        self.freq = freq
        self.phase = 0
        self.stream.start_stream()

    def stop(self) -> None:
        self.stream.stop_stream()


def scale(player: NotePlayer, key: int) -> None:
    for note in key + np.array((0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12)):
        player.play_note(int(note))
        time.sleep(0.4)


def main() -> None:
    with NotePlayer() as player:
        scale(player=player, key=24)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

